# Cline doesn´t work properly

Tags: tables

I need advice on tables in LaTeX. `\cline` does not work properly.

This:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{{A $\wedge$ B}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{B}  \\
\hline
& \textbf{P} & \textbf{O} &\textbf{X}& \textbf{N}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

gives me this:

[image]

so when I use `\cline` to handle it:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{{A $\wedge$ B}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{B}  \\
\cline{2-6}
& \textbf{P} & \textbf{O} &\textbf{X}& \textbf{N}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

but the `\cline` erased some lines. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try to add `\shorthandoff{-}` after the `\begin{document}` command, it looks that divis is an active character (the `babel` package).

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to the site! Could you turn your snippet into a complete minimum working example that starts with documentclass? It makes it easier for folks looking at your problem :)

Comment: \shorthand{-} doesnt work for me, ok i ll add it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specify six columns in the table preamble, but then you use only five.

When TeX builds the table, since it finds nothing in the last column, it doesn't consider it, so `\cline{2-6}` finds itself in trouble and the result is what you observe.

Of course, specifying `\cline{2-5}` works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{{A $\wedge$ B}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{B} & \\
\cline{2-6}
& \textbf{P} & \textbf{O} &\textbf{X}& \textbf{N} & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{{A $\wedge$ B}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{B}  \\
\cline{2-5}
& \textbf{P} & \textbf{O} &\textbf{X}& \textbf{N}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that in the first `tabular` the sixth column has been filled (with nothing printed, but there's the relative `&`.

If your aim is to produce the following table,

[image]

here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{{A $\wedge$ B}}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{B} \\
\cline{3-6}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \textbf{P} & \textbf{O} &\textbf{X}& \textbf{N} \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{A} & \textbf{P} & P & O & X & N \\
\cline{2-6}
& \textbf{O} & O & O & N & N \\
\cline{2-6}
& \textbf{N} & X & N & X & N \\
\cline{2-6}
& \textbf{N} & N & N & N & N \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

An alternative way, without `\multirow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{c}{A $\wedge$ B} \\
\midrule
A & \multicolumn{4}{c}{B} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
& \textbf{P} & \textbf{O} &\textbf{X}& \textbf{N} \\
\textbf{P} & P & O & X & N \\
\textbf{O} & O & O & N & N \\
\textbf{N} & X & N & X & N \\
\textbf{N} & N & N & N & N \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: because i need exactly this :http://i59.tinypic.com/2vtyzwx.png so i use 6 columns

Comment: @MichaelHalinár Well, your first multirow cell should straddle two columns, not one.

Answer (score 2):

You have 5 columns not 6:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A $\wedge$ B}  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{B}  \\
\cline{2-5}
     & \textbf{P} & \textbf{O} & \textbf{X} & \textbf{N} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Now try this (if you need exactly the table as per the link in your comment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{A $\wedge$ B}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{B}\\
\cline{3-6}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \textbf{P} & \textbf{O} &\textbf{X}& \textbf{N}\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{A}& \textbf{P} & P & O & X & N \\ \cline{2-6}
                  & \textbf{O} & O & O & N & N \\ \cline{2-6}
                  & \textbf{N} & X & N & X & N \\ \cline{2-6}
                  & \textbf{N} & N & N & N & N \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but i need 6. column in next row right after this two rows

Comment: Where should the sixth column be? Your image in the question shows only 5 columns.

Comment: because i need exactly this table : 
http://i59.tinypic.com/2vtyzwx.png

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but this worked

```
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
\cline{6-6}   %this added \cline
\multirow{2}{*}{{A $\wedge$ B}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{B}  \\
\cline{2-6}
& \textbf{P} & \textbf{O} &\textbf{X}& \textbf{N}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]